# HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb - scraping from a url with a dot in

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I am trying to scrape some html from a site. All other urls work but one in particular gives a problem. The url has a dot in, it's not something I can change because it is someone else's site.

```
string url = "http://blahblah.com/over-under-2.5" // not the actual url!
HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
var document = htmlWeb.Load(url);
```

It doesn't give any runtime error but the document returned is empty.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Have you tried `http://blahblah.com/over-under-2%2E5`

Comment: when you open that URL in the browser, does it work?

Comment: http://blahblah.com/over-under-2%2E5 works in the broswer, but it doesn't work in the code. document.DocumentNode is still null.

Comment: does the output look like valid HTML? It's possible that browsers can "fix" invalid HTML and still display it, but HtmlAgilityPack may not accept it\

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Uri` class to create your URL.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://blahblah.com/over-under-2.5");
HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
var page = htmlWeb.Load(uri.AbsoluteUri);
Console.WriteLine(page.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"currentpage\"]").InnerText);
```

which will output "BLAH" from the web page.

Comment: when I try that uri.AbsoluteUri is the same as the original string

Comment: so if inpsect uri.AbsoluteUri what do you get? Mine is http://blahblah.com/over-under-2.5, the same as was passed into the constructor.

Comment: Yes, but what is your result? You pass an uri-object, not a string representation of the URL this time. There is a difference.

Comment: but uri.AbsoluteUri is a string. What you say would be true if you could pass in uri directly but there is not Load method which accepts an object. I get the same result (null reference) because the string I am passing in in your code is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape Uris with:

```
string escapedString = Uri.EscapeUriString(unescapedString);
```

I might be missing the point of your question completely, though.

Comment: I think it will escape `.com` also